# datatable cell.data---input form

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, datatables

I have this page:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" >id="ButonSociete"name="ButonSociete"placeholder="Societe"> <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" >id="demande" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nom</th>
                        <th>Prenom</th>
                        <th>Societe</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Telephone</th>
                        <th>Fax</th>
                        <th>Adresse</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Createdby</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>            </table>
```

I use this datatable to add data to the table using this JS file:

```
var table = $('#demande').DataTable     (       {           dom: 'Bfrtip',          ajax: 'php/table.demande.php',          columns:            [

                {
                    "data": "Nom"
                },
                {
                    "data": "Prenom"
                },
                {
                    "data": "Societe"
                },
                {
                    "data": "Email"
                },
                {
                    "data": "Telephone"
                },
                {
                    "data": "Fax"
                },
                {
                    "data": "Adresse"
                },
                {
                    "data": "Date"
                },
                {
                    "data": "Createdby"

                }           ],          select: 'single',
                        buttons:            [
                { extend: 'edit',   editor: editor },
                {extend: "selectedSingle",
                    text: "Select",
                     action: function ( )
                    {
                    }
                }

            ]       }   );
```

When I click on the 'select' button I want the input "ButonNom" to receive data in the selected cell, I tried `table.cell(selected,0).data();`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i add this
                        var contenu = table.cell('.selected', 0).data();

```
                    $('input[name="ButonPrenom"]').val(contenu);
```

and seems to be working